# Unable to call php from html form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to call 'phpControls.php' from home.html to upload the browsed image in to a desired folder. I inspected the page in Chrome, it shows that the Upload button is not calling the php file.

The HTML code is as follows:

```
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="phpControls.php">
            <input type="file" name="browseFile" id="browseFile" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)"
                   style="width: 50%; margin-top: 1%"
                   class="btn btn-info btn-lg" > <!--style="opacity: 0"-->

            <script>
              var loadFile = function(event) {
                var output = document.getElementById('preview');
                output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
              };
            </script>

            <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" value="Upload" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" 
                   style="width: 50%; margin-top: 1%">
            </input>
        </form>
```

phpControls.php code is as follows:

```
<?php
echo "Enter php";
$target_dir = "SharedFolder/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["browseFile"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["browseFile"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
echo "Exit php";
?>
```

file_upload =on in php.ini.

I am not getting what's the mistake.

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `phpControls.php` in the same folder as the html file?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same folder.

Comment: But you wrote, when your PHP is in file named 'pageControl.php' and in form call 'phpControls.php'

Comment: `pageControl.php` and `phpControls.php` are two different files. Maybe you have the wrong filename.

Comment: Sorry typo mistake. Its 'phpControls.php'.

Comment: The script called the php file for me. Your problem is that its not calling the php file or no data is being displayed?

Comment: what is that `</button>` doing there?

Comment: It's not uploading the selected image to the SharedFolder. I put 'echo' in the php file, but they are not triggering, also I checked in Chrome inspect element Network. On clicking the Upload button it is not calling the php file.

Comment: php is a server side language so it is processed on the server only. html is client side language and is processed on the client/browser only. you can use a technique called AJAX to get the client to make requests to the server after the html file has loaded. this will require you to do some research to learn.

Comment: `<input></button>` doesn't make sense

Comment: Ohh. <input></button> changed it. Didn't work.

Comment: Yes the `<input></button>` is incorrect. You can move `</button>` but even with that it loads for me. Are you using an application like wamp/xamp to run your script? if not then it will load the php file itself showing all your code. Other than that it is working fine for me. I'm seeing "Enter phpExit php"

Comment: Also you should change `$_POST["submit"]` to `$_POST["submitBtn"]` which results with a text saying 'Enter phpFile is an image - image/jpeg.Exit php'

Comment: Yes I am using WAMP. I changed it to $_POST["submitBtn"]. No luck.

Comment: I cant really see why your file is not being called if your using WAMP because it works for me.

Comment: Now it is hitting the php, and throwing an error "Undefined index: browseFile in C:\wamp\www\AgePage\phpControls.php on line 4"

Comment: That's because you have `$_FILES["browseFile"]["name"]` on line 4, and it runs even when the form hasn't been submitted.

Answer (score 0):

**Your PHP is looking for the wrong value.** You have your HTML button set to `name="submitBtn"`, the name attribute is what you're selecting in PHP when you use `$_POST["submit"]`.

So you need to change this:
`if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {`

To this:
`if(isset($_POST["submitBtn"])) {`

Not sure if this is the only issue, but it should at least make your code run. :)

Comment: I changed it to $_POST["submitBtn"]. But did not work.

Comment: I am using WAMP to run my script. I changed made the above change you had suggested. But the php file is still not being hit.

Comment: If your problem is the PHP file getting called, you may want to try putting your PHP code in the top of the file your form is in. Then make the form submit to itself: `<form action="">`. This is much easier for testing.

Comment: I added action to the main form element, also tried to include the php in the <head>. It not being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the only reason is the wrong value being checked by isset function.
Replace your phpControls.php code to the following.

```
<?php
echo "Enter php";
$target_dir = "SharedFolder/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["browseFile"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submitBtn"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["browseFile"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
echo "Exit php";
?>
```