# php action file is not getting called on form submit

Tags: php, html, form-submit

Action file is not getting called in php form submission. I found the same problem occured [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321687/unable-to-call-php-from-html-form), but there wasn't a correct answer.

Following is the code,

**index.php**

```
<form action="form_submit.php" method="POST" class="form-group">
  <div>
    <label>Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="login_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="login_pw" class="form-control" id="InputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class ="fa fa-lock">&nbsp;</i>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**form_submit.php**

```
<?php
echo "entered";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","inventory");

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $username=$_POST['login_email'];
    $password=$_POST['login_pw'];
    $query="select * from userlogin where username='$username' and password='$password'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)
    {
        header("location:hello.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo"<script>alert('wrong password or user name if you lost your password please contact service provider')</script>";
        echo"<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

At least the `echo` on the top of the `form_submit.php` is not showing. I tried to put the submit code on the top of the `index.php` and tried the self-call `action=""`. It didn't even work.

Comment: **Warning!** _Never store passwords in clear text!_ Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you for the knowledge sir. Here what I can see is the `form_submit.php` is not getting called. How can I make sure it is called? I have an `echo` statement in the very first line but, the line is not getting called.

Comment: Check the network tab in your browsers development tools when you're trying to submit the form and you should see what file is being called and what it returns.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It's calling a url, `http://localhost/Inventory/index.php?login_email=admin%40sdfsd&login_pw=admin&submit=submit` not the `form_submit.php`

Comment: Are you using some javascript events triggered when the form i submitted? That request is a GET-request. There's nothing in the HTML form you've posted above that would make it into a GET request instead of a POST request. There must be something else going on.

Comment: I have only the `index.php`, `form_submit.php`, `hello.php` and the css file. I have done nothing with js sir. I wonder why even the request is not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line because after validatio error it is going on index.php page

```
echo"<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>"; from
```

Comment: But before it should show the alert message. Isn't it. I am not getting the alert message

Comment: use die; after echo like: echo "entered";die;

Comment: Does it make sense? First of all I want to call the `form_submit.php` for button click. I tried the `die;` and it does no changes